# Laravel 5.4 adding specific column in existing selected colum with with()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem with displaying results from my db using eloquent in laravel 5.4. I just want to specify a columns that I want to be in my results. So in my case the record is relation to another tables which I want also to specify a column that I need. Please check my eloquent:

```
return User::with(['images' => function($q){
        $q->select('user_id as userId','image_name','url');
    }])
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->select(['id as userId','name','email'])
    ->paginate(10);
```

and here's my hasMany() relations in my model:

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('Images', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

The problem with this code the images are always null.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
return User::with(['images' => function($q){
        $q->select('id', 'image_name','url');
}])
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->select(['id','name','email'])
->paginate(10);
```

You need to select the relationship key for it to find results.

Comment: its working now but it is possible to give alias to the key? like select(['id as userId,'name', 'email'])

Comment: Yeah, laravel supports `AS` inside of `select()` so that should work as expected.

Comment: Try `$q->select(['id AS userId', 'image_name', 'url']);` instead.